# Simplify default display one row when outputdata list is empty

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

```
<table>
<c:if test="${output.list == nul}">
<tr><td><input type="text" /><select></select><input type="text" />
</td>
</tr>
</c:if>
<c:forEach var="iter" items="${output.list}">
<tr><td><input type="text" /><select></select><input type="text" value="${iter.getVal()}" />
</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</tbody>
</table>
```

If my `${list}` is empty,how can I display `.clone` row without duplicating codes or using javascript?

Comment: would you like to show just empty row?

Comment: @KenBekov No,currently it display empty row but I want it to display the `tr .clone`

Comment: To show `.clone` you need `iter` anyway. Where from you going to get `iter` if your list is empty?

Comment: Do you have any idea? Just want to eliminate the hard coded js as mention above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know whether I understood your problem. If you want output one row with all content, when list is empty, try next approach:

```
  <table>
        <c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="${not empty list?(fn:length(list)-1):0}">
          <tr class="clone">
            <td>
               <input type="text" />
               <select></select>
               <input type="text" value="${list[i]!=null?list[i].getVal():''}" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </c:forEach>
 </tbody>
```

For use `fn:` namespace just add in begin of your file `<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>`

***Udate***: changed according question changes

Answer (score 1):

If the list is empty then add an empty value to the list. You can do it in the servlet or JSP but in JSP you have to write additional java code to modify the list.

```
<table>
<c:set var="list" value="${output.list}"/>
<c:if test="${empty list && list != null}">
  ${list.add(null)} 
</c:if>
<c:forEach var="iter" items="${list}">
<tr><td><input type="text" /><select></select><input type="text" value="${iter.getVal()}" />
</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What if this is not the last place where list is used? What if the list will be used somewhere else? And there is no one expects that empty list contains null.

Comment: @KenBekov I don't see the empty list is used somewhere else. The list that is used in the JSP could be instantiated if it's empty.